# android write to file doesn't write anything

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple browser for my school project, and i am trying to make a favorites class. This is the code:

```
public    class    Favorite    extends Activity{                                                   
EditText etName;
EditText etAdress;
Button bAdd;
TextView tvDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorite);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAdress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);
    bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String adress = etAdress.getText().toString();
            if (adress != null) {
                if (adress.contains("http://") || adress.contains("www.")
                        || adress.contains(".com")
                        || adress.contains(".ro")
                        || adress.contains(".org")) {

                    try {
                        FileWriter WriteFile = new FileWriter(
                                "D:\\FACULTATE\\proiect\\Browser3\\favorites.txt");
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(WriteFile);
                        out.write(name + " " + adress);
                        tvDisplay.setText("Name:   " + name
                                + "   Adress:   " + adress);
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else
                    tvDisplay
                            .setText("The adress you have entered is invalid");
            } else {
                tvDisplay.setText("You haven't entered anything");
            }
        }

    });

}
}
```

It doesn't write in the file and in the TextView either...what did i do wrong? before adding the filewriter and the try/catch, it worked displaying the two strings in the textview, but now it doesn't.

Comment: `"D:\\FACULTATE\\proiect\\Browser3\\favorites.txt"` I guess this path is not valid

Comment: Read the exception stacktrace from logcat to learn that you don't have a `D:` path on your Android device.

Comment: `"D:\\FACULTATE\\proiect\\Browser3\\favorites.txt")` this definitely won't work on an Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your filename is wrong - this does not look like an android path - more like some windows stuff:

```
D:\\FACULTATE\\proiect\\Browser3\\favorites.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.example.testing;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Favorite extends Activity
{
    EditText etName;
    EditText etAdress;
    Button bAdd;
    TextView tvDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAdress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);
        bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String adress = etAdress.getText().toString();
                if (adress != null)
                {
                    if (adress.contains("http://") || adress.contains("www.") || adress.contains(".com") || adress.contains(".ro")
                            || adress.contains(".org"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "favorite.txt");
                            FileWriter WriteFile = new FileWriter(file);
                            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(WriteFile);
                            out.write(name + " " + adress);
                            tvDisplay.setText("Name:   " + name + "   Adress:   " + adress);
                            out.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        tvDisplay.setText("The adress you have entered is invalid");
                }
                else
                {
                    tvDisplay.setText("You haven't entered anything");
                }
    }
    });
    }
}
Dont' forget to add 
 "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
 in AndroidManifest.xml
it Works for me.